# Transferring IList(Of T) using SignalR in desktop application

Tags: vb.net, signalr

I need to do some testing with SignalR so I have two console applications - first serving as SignalR hub (server) and second SignalR client. I need to transfer lists of custom objects, not some primitive data like strings or integers. I dont want to use WCF because of its complexity.

Hub:

```
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs
Imports DataContract
<HubName("Repository")>
Public Class RepositoryHub
  Inherits Hub
  Public Function SelectTasks() As IList(Of Task)
    Dim tasks As New List(Of Task)
    tasks.Add(New Task With {.Id = 1, .Code = "A", .Assignment = "Assignment A"})
    tasks.Add(New Task With {.Id = 2, .Code = "B", .Assignment = "Assignment B"})
    tasks.Add(New Task With {.Id = 3, .Code = "C", .Assignment = "Assignment C"})
    Return tasks
  End Function
  Public Overrides Function OnConnected() As Threading.Tasks.Task
    Console.WriteLine(Context.ConnectionId)
    Return MyBase.OnConnected()
  End Function
End Class

Public Class Task
  Public Property Id As Integer
  Public Property Code As String
  Public Property Assignment As String
End Class
```

Server:

```
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Hosting
Module ServerModule
  Sub Main()
    Using WebApp.Start(Of OwinConfiguration)("http://localhost:8080")
      Console.ReadLine()
    End Using
  End Sub
End Module

Public Class OwinConfiguration
  Public Sub Configuration(app As IAppBuilder)
    app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll)
    app.MapSignalR()
  End Sub
End Class
```

Client:

```
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client
Imports DataContract
Module ClientModule
  Sub Main()
    Dim repositoryHub As IHubProxy
    Dim connection As New HubConnection("http://localhost:8080")
    repositoryHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("Repository")
    repositoryHub.On(Of IList(Of Task))("SelectTasks", Sub(t)
                                                         Console.WriteLine(t.Count)
                                                       End Sub)
    connection.Start().Wait()
    repositoryHub.Invoke(Of IList(Of Task))("SelectTasks").Wait()
    Console.ReadLine()
  End Sub
End Module
```

Breakpoint is always reached in SelectTasks method, but never in anonymous Sub(t) method in client, where is processing of data received from server.

Answer (score 0):

It was misunderstanding in SignalR usage. Client should be like this:

```
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client
Imports DataContract
Module ClientModule
  Sub Main()
    Dim repositoryHub As IHubProxy
    Dim connection As New HubConnection("http://localhost:8080")
    repositoryHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("Repository")
    connection.Start().Wait()
    Dim tasks = repositoryHub.Invoke(Of IList(Of Task))("SelectTasks")
    tasks.Wait()
    Console.WriteLine(tasks.Result.Count)
    Console.ReadLine()
  End Sub
End Module
```